# Why does 'shell' opening an executable in a Visual Basic Script sometimes give a 'run time error 5' but not always?

Tags: excel, vba

I am playing around with the basics of VBS and have a very simple Visual Basic script which executes a file using `shell`.
I am using Excel under Windows 10.

```
Sub Whatever()

Dim Example_One As String
Example_One = "C:\Users\IEUser\python-3.8.0.exe"
Shell Example_One, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

The weird thing is that some files will run (e.g. Python as above) while others e.g. VLC, WinRAR give the error: `Run time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.`

I simply cannot figure out why some .exe files will run and others will not. I thought it might be something to do with how the installation works but `ChromeSetup.exe` works while `VLC.exe` does not (even though they both ask "Do you want this app to make changes to your device?" (Python has it's own installer). Double-clicking all files in Windows Explorer runs them as normal (they don't ask for any special rights).